# iOS Smart App Banners - showing on iPad, not on iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, banner

As I'm not using the affilate stuff, I implemented the Smart App Banner on my website like this:

```
<meta name="apple-itunes-app" content="app-id=...">
```

On my iPad Mini (iOS 7.0.2) it's showing up without any problem, on my iPhone 5 (same version) it's not showing up.

Both got the app installed already (the banner should show "Open").

Do you know what could be wrong?
Thank you!

Comment: show some code and your condition for iPhone and iPad.

Comment: Oops, it didn't save the code example. There's no condition as both are intended to show the banner, but only the iPad does.

Comment: Are you certain you haven't visited that site earlier with your iPhone and closed the Smart App Banner? Try clearing cache / website data from settings.

Comment: I tried, but still it's not showing up. The page and app are completely new, I never canceled the banner for it

Comment: I'm encountering with the same problem only I can see the banner in IPhones but in IPads I can't see it not- it used to work...

Comment: nope... but it's working now, without me doing anything about it.

Comment: It seems to me that, once closed, the banner will never show up again. Or at least for some time... Which I don't know =/

Comment: That's true but it's intended. Once you closed that banner on an iOS device, you won't see it again on that device

Answer (score 0):

Just a heads up, these banners only show on safari, no other ios browsers .

Comment: please don't post the same answer to several questions - they either don't fit exactly or the question is a duplicate and should be flagged as such

Comment: @kleopatra never knew about the flag, apologies and thank you!